# How does the OS calculate file sizes?

Tags: unix, operating-system, filesystems

I like to know how a filesize on a operating system is calculated?

My best guess is that the OS somehow keeps track of a list of files and all the associated disk chunks they occupy, and simply multiply the (count of disk chunks * chunk size), but this would not give the exact filesize since there might be unused space in a chunk, then i guess it could loop thru all bytes of the last chunk till it finds a null termnination char.

I guess this is OS dependant but im just trying to understand the overall picture but otherwise im looking for answers related to unix :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

Comment: thanks devnull that answered my question :) could you create a answer instead of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux and other Unix-like operating systems, an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) stores all the information about a file except its name and data content.  When a file is created, it is assigned both a name and an inode number, which is an integer that is unique within the filesystem.

The inode structure includes the file mode (that determines the permissions and file type), owner id, group id, system and user flags, size, timestamp (creation/access/modification time), link count, device id (in order to identify the device containing the file), and pointers to disk block that store the actual contents of the file.